# Powershell script fails to load modules when run it using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start in c#?

Tags: c#, powershell, system.diagnostics, windows-scripting

When running PS script using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` PowerShell modules doesn't get loaded hence script fails, but same script runs successfully when executed manually on the server,
Below is my C# code snippet,

```
string ExecPath = @"C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
System.Diagnostics.Process exeProcess =
    new System.Diagnostics.Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            FileName = ExecPath
        }
    };
exeProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" -NoLogo -Sta -NoProfile -NonInteractive -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -File D:\MyPowerShell.ps1");
exeProcess.Start();
```

Exception is below,

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'ServerManager' was not loaded 
because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At D:\MyPowerShell.ps1:9 char:1
+ Import-Module ServerManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (ServerManager:String) , FileNot 
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I have tried importing the module with its full path, but fails with same exception. 
What should be done to make the script work same as like its running manually ?

Comment: the module path is likely NOT set properly for that account. try checking `$env:PSModulePath` for that account to see if the module is on that path. you may also want to check `Get-Module -ListAvailable` and `Get-InstalledModule` for that account.

Comment: the issue was with the C# project config, it was configured with Platform x86 where as its being run on x64. It is working as expected modifying it to Platform x64.

Comment: thank you for the problem ID - and the fix! [*grin*]